# PHP Should I put curly braces around a variable being used as a function name?

Tags: php, php-5.3

It's been suggested in my code that I put {} around a variable that's being used as a function name.

e.g.:

```
$myObject = new peopleObject();
$varArray = array('name', 'dob', 'address1', ...)

foreach ($varArray as $var) {
    $objFunction = 'set' . ucfirst($var);
    $myObject->$objFunction($_POST['$var']);
}
```

For this line:

```
$myObject->$objFunction($_POST['$var']);
```

It's been suggested I do this to remove ambiguity:

```
$myObject->{$objFunction}($_POST['$var']);
```

Is this necessary? Is there any advantage?  I can't find anything in the PSR about doing this.

Comment: doesnt look ambiguous to me, so no advantage here but im sure some smart person can come up with a case where with further concatenating or some other usage that the brackets become useful

Comment: Your case specifically doesn't apply, but when you migrate to PHP 7 (hopefully soon :) ), you can run into some weird problems, check [this out](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)